# How to change admin panel pages separately for each model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I need to add on the root model page (not a page for record editing) some fields for editing records in other models and the save button to save them.
For example

[image]

This fields going to save data in tables with one record limitation so each field will save data to specified record in specified model.

This is only example. So how to make custom editions on model pages in admin panel? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can custom edit admin templates specifically for each model. The problem is covered in detail in [Django admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates)